# Where to put a "AFNetworking UIImageView" meant to be displayed in several controllers ?

Tags: ios

I have an UIImageView filled with AFNetworking shared between several controllers. Right now I call it in each of them so this code is duplicated:

```
   _headerView = [UIImageView new];
    NSString *headerPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"domain/header.jpg"];
    media.mediaImageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:headerPath];
    [_headerView  setImageWithURL:media.mediaImageURL placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] ];
    _headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 130);
    _headerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    _headerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    _headerView.tag = 313;
```

What is the best practise for this case ? A custom view or imageView ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest creating a UIImageView category

```
+ (instancetype)imageViewWithURL:(NSURL *)url {

     UIImageView *headerView = [UIImageView new];
     [headerView  setImageWithURL:url placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"] ];
     headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 130);
     headerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
     headerView.clipsToBounds = YES;
     headerView.tag = 313;

     return headerView;
}
```

and then call it in controller like

```
_headerView = [UIImageView imageViewWithURL:media.mediaImageURL];
```

Comment: The reference to `self.tableView.frame.size.width` won't work if the category is for `UIImageView`.

Comment: Thank you, categories are life changing !

Answer (score 1):

Your best option would be creating a category for `UITableViewController` and import it in the view controllers that use the code.